# Как ускорить запрос в Clickhouse c массивом

Tags: python, sql, массивы, clickhouse

Есть запрос, он выполняется через python

```
select distinct user_id
from firb
    array join properties
where event_date >= toDate('2021-07-01') and 
      event_date < toDate('2022-01-01')  and 
      properties.key = 'abonent_type' and
      (properties.string_value = 'neabonent' 
       or properties.string_value = 'неабонент')
```

Необходимо вытащить user_id за последние 6 месяцев у кого abonent_type "неабонент".
Данных очень много , запрос выполняется очень долго, как можно ускорить его? Уже пробовал и через **has** и через **indexOf** , суть от этого не меняется, так же долго.
Схема таблицы

```
firb
(
    event_date                     DateTime,
    event_name                      String,
    `event_params.key` Array(String),
    `event_params.string_value` Array(String),
    `event_params.int_value` Array(Int64),
    `event_params.float_value` Array(Float32),
    user_id                         Int64,
    `properties.key` Array(String),
    `properties.string_value` Array(String),
    `properties.int_value` Array(Int64),
    `properties.double_value` Array(Float32),
    `properties.set_timestamp_micros` Array(Int64),
    device_category                 String,
    device_mobile_brand_name        String,
    device_operating_system         String,
    device_operating_system_version String,

)
```

Comment: покажите, пожалуйста, схему таблицы.

Comment: @vladimir отписался в вопросе) извиняюсь за долгий ответ